# insert images on egeloen ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, symfony

Hi I'm using symfony with ckeditor bundle to write content. But I can't find a way to insert images within ckeditor. Can someone have ever try using it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert image through CKEditor is just clicking on the 'picture' button.

But I guess you mean "upload on the server some picture, and insert them on the text.

And you should take a look to [IvoryCKEditorBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/index.html). And so, checking [FMElfinderBundle](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle), which could do what you need.

Comment: Yes it was what I meant ! Whenever I tried to upload a picture it doesn't show up.

Comment: I will take a look at your link to see what I can find.

Comment: you will need to add some custom upload method if you don't want to go with FMElfinderBundle. Also, take a look at your dir permission, and www-data (apache) permission